# Android: Which events do wakeup a device

Tags: android, events, sleep, wakeup

I have written an android application and now there is a problem.

If my application is running and I power off my device, then sometimes it just wakes up after about 8 seconds and then the screen is on and it shows my application again.

My question is:
Which events or processing constraints (like handling broadcast intents) do wakeup a device?

Edit: Will an alarm with RCT_WAKEUP turn on the device screen?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The AlarmManager won't actually turn the screen on for you. You can use a wakelock instead.

```
PowerManager.WakeLock wakelock;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    .........

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakelock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, "AlarmReceiver");
    wakelock.acquire();       
}
```

When you're done with the activity just be sure to release the wakelock:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    wakelock.release();
}
```

You also need to add the wake lock permission in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to have to include this extra permission you can use the following code in your activity instead of using a wakelock:

```
this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 
But my question was not HOW to wakeup the device and how to keep the screen on, but WHICH events will wakeup my device. I don't want to wakeup my device, it is not a phone and not a tablet but a custom device and it has to be in sleep mode for a certain amount of time without turning on spontanously.